# Refresh a modified iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have a little app. that imite functions of a CMS, change texts, paragraphs and images.

The page that will be modified are in a iframe, I do all the modifications and save this new texts and images, but not when I "click" on submit aparently refresh the page but I must to refresh again the page manually for see these changes.

I dont know what to do for see these changes without press F5 to refresh...

This is the iframe:

```
<iframe  id="probando" src="<?php echo $url; ?>"  name="probando"></iframe>
```

PhP code:

```
<?php
$directorioInicial = "./";    //Especifica el directorio a leer
$rep = opendir($directorioInicial);    //Abrimos el directorio
echo "<div class='button' id='mostrar'>Mostrar archivos</div>";
echo "<div id='acordeon' class='propiedadesCaja'>";
echo "<ul>";
while ($todosArchivos = readdir($rep)) {  
    if ($todosArchivos != '..' && $todosArchivos != '.' && $todosArchivos != ''     && strpos($todosArchivos, '.html') && !is_dir($todosArchivos)) {
       echo "<li class='listaPaginas' ><a class='listado' href=" .       $todosArchivos . " target='probando'>" . $todosArchivos . "</a></li>";       
//    . $directorioInicial . "/"
    }
}
closedir($rep);     
clearstatcache();    
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
$url = "";
if (isset($_POST['textarea'])) {
    $url = $_POST['textareaPagina'];
    $salida = $_POST['textarea'];
    $archivo = fopen($url, "w+");
    fwrite($archivo, $salida);

    fclose($archivo);
    clearstatcache();
}
  ?>
```

How I can refresh the page? With php, JavaScript...?

JQuery code:

```
 $("#probando").contents().find("p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,span,ul,li,a").on("click", function (e) {
                            swal({
                                title: "Nuevo texto",
                                text: "Escribe el texto deseado:",
                                type: "input",
                                showCancelButton: true,
                                closeOnConfirm: false,
                                animation: "slide-from-top",
                                inputPlaceholder: "Nuevo texto"},
                            function (inputValue) {
                                if (inputValue === false)
                                    return false;
                                if (inputValue === "") {
                                    swal.showInputError("¡No has escrito nada!");
                                    return false
                                }
                                swal("¡Muy bien!", "Nuevo texto: " + inputValue, "success");
                                $(e.target).text(inputValue);
                                var contenido = $("#probando").contents().find('html').prop('outerHTML');
                                $("#contenido").text(contenido);
                            });


                        });
```

Comment: Modificated? Do you mean Modified?

Comment: haha yes sorry modified :S

Comment: Never mind... Mistakes happen.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't actually see anywhere where you are putting contents into the iFrame. Also You wouldn't need to refresh, it should appear on it's own.

Comment: Yeah, but I must to refresh for the first time If I dont refresh I see the old text.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`document.getElementById('probando').contentWindow.location.reload(true);`

call this when you want the iFrame to reload.

Comment: I tryed, but not found :(

Comment: When exactly are you trying to make the iFrame Refresh?

Comment: When I click on submit